# When a skald uses song of marching, do you include rage powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, skald

While working on a character that uses the [Skald](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald) class I had a thought. The class is a combination of bard and barbarian, they use song to grant themselves and others rage. At 3rd level they gain the ability called song of marching.

Song of marching

> At 3rd level, a skald can use raging song to inspire his allies to move faster without suffering from fatigue. By expending 1 round of raging song, the skald invigorates allies within 60 feet, who may hustle for the next hour; this movement counts as a walk (not a hustle) for the purpose of accruing nonlethal damage and fatigue. The skald must continue to perform the song for the remainder of the hour, otherwise its effects end, but only 1 round of raging song is expended for that hour.

Skald's rage states

> When starting an inspired rage, the skald chooses which rage powers (if any) to add to the song, and all affected allies gain the benefit of these rage powers, using the skald’s level as their effective barbarian level. The skald uses his skald level as his barbarian level for the purpose of selecting rage powers that require a minimum barbarian level. If the rage power’s effects depend on the skald’s ability modifier (such as lesser spirit totem), affected allies use the skald’s ability modifier instead of their own for the purposes of this effect.

So am I correct in my thinking that any rage power choosen should affect song of marching during its entire duration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Skald's rage powers are only granted during an Inspired Rage

A skald's rage powers are only available to allies affected by the skald's Inspired Rage, as described at the start of the [Rage Powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Rage-Powers-Ex-) class feature:

> **When starting an inspired rage**, the skald chooses which rage powers (if any) to add to the song, and all affected allies gain the benefit of these rage powers, using the skald’s level as their effective barbarian level.

[Inspired Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Inspired-Rage-Su-) is a type of [Raging Song](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald#TOC-Raging-Song-Su-) that works similarly to a bard's [Inspire Courage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/#TOC-Inspire-Courage-Su-) performance.

> Inspired Rage (Su) At 1st level, affected allies gain a +2 morale bonus to Strength and Constitution and a +1 morale bonus on Will saving throws, but also take a –1 penalty to AC.

Comment: Ah, so raging song is made up of inspired rage and song of marching, and its that single aspect of raging song which applies rage powers, ok.

Comment: @Fering Raging Song has a number of options, depending on the skald's level. "Inspired Rage" and "Song of Marching" are different options, assumed to be mutually exclusive. The limitation that *"A bard cannot have more than one bardic performance in effect at one time"* should also apply to Raging Song, because *"A raging song counts as the bard’s bardic performance special ability for any effect that affects bardic performances"*.